# WinBUGS Interface

Tags: probability-or-statistics, interoperability

Has anyone created on [WinBUGS (Bayesian inference Using Gibbs Sampling)](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/welcome.shtml) interface with Mathematica similar to BugsXLA for Excel? I'd like to setup the model, define the evidence in a notebook and then analyze the results of the MCMC (Markov chain Monte Carlo) runs.

Comment: Mathematica can do a lot of the necessary tricks natively. A v6 implementation of similar functionality can be found [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6900/). The v8 capabilities in the `Probability` area and wrt distributions have grown enormously.

Comment: Agreed. I would like to use Mathematica's probability functions to fit the posterior data produced by WinBUGS and transform into an empirical distribution.

Comment: I'm using RLink now to call R and run rjags and LaplacesDemon.  It's easy to export the chains back into Mathematica.  You might want to try RLink to call R2WinBUGS.  Unfortunately, I don't have Windows or I would provide you with a starter template.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Mathematica 9 features built-in [support for R](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-integration-with-r/) and automated support for simulation of [Markov chains and queues](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/markov-chains-and-queues/).

Perhaps one can perform the entire computation now entirely within Mathematica.

Comment: I would really like to see some examples of Bayesian calculations with Markov chains!  Do you have any?

Comment: Examples would, e.g. from the WINBUGS sets would be very instructive.